# How to access state inside map array

Tags: javascript, react-native, state

I have the following problem:

```
this.state.renderMap.map(function(name, index) {
    return (
        <View style={styles.checkBoxWrapper} key={index}>
            <CheckBox title={name} value={() => {this.state.name} onValueChange={() => console.log(name)} />
            <Text>{name}</Text>
        </View>
    );
}, this)
```

As you can see, I am trying to render a map array and it works as intended. My only problem is, that I don't know how to access the state, which is "this.state.{name of current array item}". Could someone help me out? I tried using several approaches and none have worked out so far.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off of your description I believe this is what you're looking for. I've updated the map to use an arrow function to help limit scoping issues.

I also updated the `value` function. I believe that you meant state variables are named like this.

If you had an item with `name: "foo"`, the state object would be `this.state.foo`? This solution accomplishes accessing state in that way.

```
this.state.renderMap.map((name, index) => {
    return (
        <View style={styles.checkBoxWrapper} key={index}>
            <CheckBox title={name} value={() => this.state[name]} onValueChange={() => console.log(name)} />
            <Text>{name}</Text>
        </View>
    );
})
```

Comment: This worked as intended, I just changed `value={() => this.state[name]}` to `value={this.state[name]}` as I received the error "Invalid prop 'value' of type 'function' supplied to CheckBox, expected 'boolean'". As it couldn't recognize the arrow function, I just removed it. Thanks :)

Comment: @user8598567 ah, I was wondering if that would happen, but I left it as a function because I didn't have documentation on `CheckBox`. Glad you figured it out and I could be of help!

Answer (score -1):

The wrong value of `this` is probably bound to your function; try changing your map to be an arrow function

`this.state.renderMap.map((name, index)=> {`

Comment: Yes, using an arrow function will give access to your state variables inside the map function, however if you have `name` as a state variable and you're first parameter in the map function is also called `name` is a little confusing.
Also if you have `name` as a key in your renderMap array then you can do,
`this.state.renderMap.map(function(arrayItem, idx) => {
     return(
         arrayItem.name
         )
})` should give you the name of your renderMap array.

Comment: It's not an issue of binding `this`. `map` accepts `this` as a seconds argument which he is passing when he calls it.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, using an arrow function will give access to your state variables inside the map function, however if you have `name` as a state variable and you're first parameter in the map function is also called `name` is a little confusing.
Also if you have `name` as a key in your renderMap array then you can do,
`this.state.renderMap.map(function(arrayItem, idx) => {
     return(
         arrayItem.name
         )
})` should give you the name of your renderMap array.

Comment: It's not an issue of binding `this`. `map` accepts `this` as a seconds argument which he is passing when he calls it.